# JAVA - Convert decimal MAC address into hexadecimal MAC address

Tags: java, hex, decimal, mac-address, converters

I want a method to convert a decimal format MAC address to HEX format. 
I have written this below method. Do you see any flaws in it? Any coding practices that should be followed? Anything I am missing here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String macDec = "76.177.205.33.164.80";
    convertToHex(macDec);
    System.out.println(macDec + " should be converted to 4CB1CD21A450");
}

private static void convertToHex(String macDec) {
    String[] macs = macDec.split("\\.");
    String hexMac = null;
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    for(String mac : macs) {
        hexMac = Integer.toHexString(Integer.valueOf(mac));
        buff.append(hexMac.toUpperCase());
    }
    System.out.println(buff);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `StringBuffer` (java 5 introduced `StringBuilder`). You're using `Integer.valueOf` when you should be using `Integer.parseInt`. I would prefer a method that returned a result - let the caller display it. And, assuming you're using Java 8+, you could just stream and convert with a `map`. Like,

```
private static String convertToHex(String macDec) {
    return Arrays.stream(macDec.split("\\."))
            .map(mac -> Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(mac)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining()).toUpperCase();
}
```

I moved the `toUpperCase()` at the end. Use whichever version you find easiest to read.

Comment: How do we make this method return Optional<String>? Wrapping it with Optional.of doesn't seem clean.    private static String convertToHex(String macDec) {
    return Optional.of(Arrays.stream(macDec.split("\\."))
            .map(mac -> Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(mac)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining()).toUpperCase());
}

Comment: Why should it be an optional `String`? Your posted version was `void`.

Comment: I understand. I am just asking. I forgot to use Optional earlier. I learnt using Optional is a best practice.

Comment: My version can never return `null`. So making it optional just introduces an extra layer of complexity. It might throw an exception, but in all other cases where something might return null (including `""`) it should return `""`. Anyway, you could use `Optional.ofNullable` if you want to be silly. I'm not the Java cops. And `Optional` only has a few factory methods available.